# Can the word "vector" be used in the context of non-infectious diseases?

Tags: american-english

According to one dictionary, vector (outside of physics, mathematics and computing)  means "any agent that carries out and transmits a disease." Does this mean the word is limited to infectious diseases (which can be spread through transmission) only? Would be it acceptable to use it in the following sentence:

"He thought many in the crack-infested neighborhood were vectors of addiction."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Presumably most people who become "infected" by addiction didn't get to that point entirely unaided. I don't see why you can't (metaphorically?) refer to other people (dealers, other addicts, tolerant friends, etc.) who facilitate/encourage behaviour leading to addiction as ***vectors***, since effectively they are "spreading" the problem. But I think this is essentially just a matter of opinion / writing advice.

Comment: Meaning that the persons in the neighborhood spread addiction to others?

Comment: Yes, thi s is what I'm trying to tell the reader.

Comment: In that case it could be used. It might be interpreted literally, if one allows that addiction is a kind of disease, or metaphorically, borrowing the meaning from literal disease for use in something that is not deemed to be a disease.

Comment: It is a valid metaphorical use.  Go for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*'Vector'* sits a little uncomfortably in the context described in the OP's question.  As EL&U member FumbleFingers points out, addiction is state that might be induced in, or inherent in, a person's physiological and/or psychological make-up, but it is generally not transmissible between people.

The difficulty with *'vector'* is that we have a strong association with the sense of it indicating a carrier of an infectious disease.  Turning to the Oxford English Dictionary for a moment:

> vector ▪ I.vector, n.
>   (ˈvɛktə(r))
>   [a. L. vector, agent-noun f. vehĕre to carry. So (in sense 1) Sp. and Pg. vector, F. vecteur.]
>
> 3. a. Med. and Biol. A person, animal, or plant which carries a pathogenic agent and acts as a potential source of infection for members of another species. Also transf. Cf. carrier 1 l (i).
>      *1922 [see Arthropoda, arthropod]. 1944 Nature 5 Aug. 167/2 Regular transmission of viruses by the egg of the host plant (the insect vector does not concern us unless it suffers) probably does not occur. 1963 R. Carson Silent Spring xvi. 220 An even more serious problem concerns the vector of yellow fever. 1972 Lancet 17 June 1338/2 The stethoscope is yet another vector of pathogenic organisms. 1974 Passmore & Robson Compan. Med. Stud. III. xii. 64/2 The spread of each of the insect-borne diseases depends on a complicated chain of events involving..a reservoir of infection which may be either in man or in other animals,..the insect vector and..a susceptible human population. 1976 Dumfries & Galloway Standard 25 Dec. 8/6 A small boy recovered after being bitten by a rabid bat, it being thought that the disease had been modified by passage through this unusual vector.*

There is, however, room for an argument that a vector could be carrying any agent that effects a change upon the people or things that the vector comes into contact with.  One might talk about *'vectors'* (usually viruses) carrying 'positive' changes such as improved genetic material into biological hosts, or even self propagating computer code that corrected errors in computer text or programming.

The context portrayed in the OP's question is a *'crack-infested neighborhood'*, and the suggestion appears to be that the dealers and distributors of the drug *'crack'* are the vectors of addiction.  Strictly speaking the 'people' the OP referred to are the vectors of the drugs which are being distributed (and equally they are the vectors of the cash being returned back to the major suppliers).  Essentially though, we already have well known words for these people, such as *'distributors'*, *'dealers'* and most precisely, *'pushers'*.

One might say, more conventionally, that these people are *'facilitators of addiction'*, or *'links in the chain of addiction'*, or more poetically (albeit in a bleak sense), *'vectors of misery'*, or more familiarly, *'purveyors of misery'* .  Ultimately there is nothing in the sense of the word *'vector'* that would forbid its use in the context of the OP's question, but conventional usage would suggest several alternatives.

Comment: I think I agree with all that. Although one could argue that it's ok as a metaphorical use of the word, for me the metaphor is too close to the truth, seeing as addiction is a medical condition. "Uncomfortable" is exactly the right word. It works quite nicely in your "vectors of misery", though. In the context of misery it's clearer that the user of "vector" is metaphorical.